# Owl Carousel - Flex-box bug / Error

Tags: javascript, html, css, owl-carousel

I've been stuck on the problem for a couple of weeks. I'm trying to apply the justify-content:center and align-items:center to the Owl Carousel but it seems to always be uncentered. I've tried a bunch different ways to get it to properly center vertically and horizontally. First way I tried was to get rid of Container it was wrapped in that had the flex properties of justify/align. But that didn't work. Secondly, was giving it a position of 50% / 50% horizontal / vertical but that messes up the rest of my page. There was more many more things I tried but I forgot.

This is the center of my page.
[image]

Thank you for reading

```
   #ColumnContainer {
    display:flex;
    justify-content:center;
    align-items:center;
    height:100vh;
    flex-flow:row wrap;
    flex-shrink:1;
}

    #owl {
  height:40%;
  width:40%;
}

    <div id="owl" class="owl-carousel owl-centered">
  <div><img src="pic1.jpg" alt=""></div>
  <div><img src="pic2.jpg" alt=""></div>
</div>

$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
  items : 1,
  itemsDesktop : false,
  itemsDesktopSmall : false,
  itemsTablet: false,
  itemsMobile : false,
  slideSpeed : 300,
  paginationSpeed : 400,
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="row">

    <div class="col-lg-3 bg-danger"></div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 bg-primary">
        <div class="container m-0 p-0">
            !------Owl Carousel-----------
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 bg-black"></div>
</div>
```

This is one way to do it,
if you Want to do it with flex then change the row to "d-flex flex-row flex-fill"
and then make boxes out of the columns.